# How do I specify get and set methods/functions as part of a class' property in PHP?

Tags: php, object, setter, getter

Using PHP, how do I define/declare getter and setter methods/functions as part of the declaration of a property in a class?

What I'm trying to do is specify the getter and setter methods as part of a property, instead of declaring separate `set_propertyName($value)` and `get_propertyName()` functions/methods.

What I've got:

```
class my_entity {
    protected $is_new;
    protected $eid; // entity ID for an existing entity
    public function __construct($is_new = FALSE, $eid = 0) {
        $this->is_new = $is_new;
        if ($eid > 0) {
            $this->set_eid($eid);
        }
    }

    // setter method
    public function set_eid($eid) {
        $is_set = FALSE;
        if (is_numeric($eid)) {
            $this->eid = intval($eid);
            $is_set = TRUE;
        }
        return $is_set;
    }
}
```

What I want (without making $this->eid an object):

```
class my_entity {
    protected $is_new;
    // entity ID for an existing entity
    protected $eid {
      set: function($value) {
        $is_set = FALSE;
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $this->eid = intval($value);
            $is_set = TRUE;
        }
        return $is_set;

      }, // end setter

    }; 
    public function __construct($is_new = FALSE, $eid = 0) {
        $this->is_new = $is_new;
        if ($eid > 0) {
            $this->set_eid($eid);
        }
    }

    // setter method/function removed
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible in PHP.

Comment: I've seen something similar done before (maybe in the PHP manual, maybe somewhere else).

Comment: As per I know, This is C# style setter/getter code not PHP styled.

Comment: In php, __get and __set method is way to go, See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: This was [proposed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax-v1.2) for PHP 5.6, but the vote failed to get the necessary 2/3 majority, so it won't be implemented.... but aside from syntactic sugar, what does the C# getter/setter give you that writing getter/setter methods doesn't?

Comment: @MarkBaker : It gives me a way of 'binding' anonymous functions to a property. If you turn your comment into an answer, combined with my comment, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [proposed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax) for PHP 5.5, but the [vote](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax-v1.2) failed to get the necessary 2/3 majority required to accept it into core, so it won't be implemented (despite the code to implement that change having been submitted).

It's entirely possible (with the plethora of new PHP engines and Hacklang currently appearing) that it will be resubmitted at a future time, especially if Hacklang decides to implement it; but for the moment the option of using C# getters/setters isn't available in PHP

Answer (score 1):

PHP only allows one getter and one setter function per class, they are the `__get` & `__set` magic methods. These two magic methods must handle get and set requests for all private/inaccessible properties. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

```
private function set_eid($id)
{
    //set it...
    $this->eid = $id;
}

private function get_eid($id)
{
    //return it...
    return $this->eid;
}

public function __set($name, $value)
{
    switch($name)
    {
        case 'eid':
            $this->set_eid($value);
        break;
    }
}

public function __get($name)
{
    switch($name)
    {
        case 'eid':
            return $this->get_eid();
        break;
    }
}
```

In the 2 switch statements you could also add the names of other properties.

It's important to remember that `__get` and `__set` are only called if the variable is inaccessible, this means that when getting or setting from inside the class you will still have to manually call `set__eid`.

Comment: My getter and setter methods/functions need to be public. The ones in your answer are private. Also, your code is more verbose than mine (first block) while it essentially does the same thing.

Comment: you can make `get_eid` & `set_eid` public, it will still work. The only thing that needs to be private is `$this->eid`.

Comment: With regards to verbose, you can style the code however you like, the only required parts are `__get` & `__set`, you could handle everything in there directly.